# State stored in context has the proper value, but then returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, web3js

I am using context to get a web3 wallet address. Routing is accomplished through `react-router-dom` . When the user first connects their wallet and goes to the `explore` page the state persists for a split second and then the component re-renders and it goes null. But when the user disconnects their wallet and connects their wallet again (not refreshing the page) then application works as expected.
This is causing broken UI elements that are based on the `walletAddress` state (in context).
**index.tsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";
import { Web3OnboardProvider, init } from "@web3-onboard/react";
import { AcreDappProvider } from "./providers/AcreDappProvider/AcreDappProvider";
import injectedModule from "@web3-onboard/injected-wallets";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const Application = () => {
  const ALCHEMY_API_KEY =
  const APP_ID = 
  const SERVER_URL = 
  const injected = injectedModule();
  const network = "mainnet";
  const rpcAPIKey = 
  const rpcUrl = 

  // initialize Onboard
  const web3onboard = init({
    wallets: [injected],
    chains: [
      {
        id: network == "mainnet" ? "0x1" : "5",
        token: "ETH",
        label: "Goerli Testnet",
        rpcUrl,
      },
    ],
  });
  return (
    <MoralisProvider appId={`${APP_ID}`} serverUrl={`${SERVER_URL}`}>
      <Web3OnboardProvider web3Onboard={web3onboard}>
        <AcreDappProvider>
          <App />
        </AcreDappProvider>
      </Web3OnboardProvider>
    </MoralisProvider>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
    <Application />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.tsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AcreDappProvider } from "./providers/AcreDappProvider/AcreDappProvider";
import { Web3OnboardProvider, init } from "@web3-onboard/react";
import injectedModule from "@web3-onboard/injected-wallets";
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";

import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";
import CreateListingLander from "./pages/CreateListingLander";
import CreateListingPage from "./pages/CreateListingPage";
import ExplorePage from "./pages/ExplorePage";
import PropertyDetailPage from "./pages/PropertyDetailPage";
import AccountPageLayout from "./pages/account/AccountPageLayout";
import MyPropertiesPage from "./pages/account/MyPropertiesPage";
import MyBidsPage from "./pages/account/MyBidsPage";
import NotificationsPage from "./pages/account/NotificationsPage";
import ErrorPage from "./pages/ErrorPage";
import AccountHelpPage from "./pages/account/AccountHelpPage";
import AccountBlankPage from "./pages/account/AccountBlankPage";

function App() {

  return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route index element={<Homepage />} />
              <Route
                path="property/list/landing"
                element={<CreateListingLander />}
              />
              <Route path="property/list/new" element={<CreateListingPage />} />
              <Route path="explore" element={<ExplorePage />} />
              <Route
                path="property/:address/:tokenId"
                element={<PropertyDetailPage />}
              />
              <Route path="account" element={<AccountPageLayout />}>
                <Route path="properties" element={<MyPropertiesPage />} />
                <Route path="bids" element={<MyBidsPage />} />
                <Route path="notifications" element={<NotificationsPage />} />
                <Route path="help" element={<AccountHelpPage />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<AccountBlankPage />} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage status="404." />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ContextProvider**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AcreDappContext from "../context";
import { useConnectWallet } from "@web3-onboard/react";
//import {contract} from '../../contracts/TestContract.js';

function AcreDappProvider({ children }) {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState();
  const [contractABI, setContractABI] = useState(/* contract.abi */); //Smart Contract ABI here
  const [marketAddress, setMarketAddress] = useState(""); //Smart Contract Address Here
  const dappId = 

  const [{ wallet}] = useConnectWallet();


  useEffect(
    () => setWalletAddress(wallet ? wallet.accounts[0].address : null)
    ,[wallet]);

  return (
    <AcreDappContext.Provider
      value={{
        walletAddress,
        setWalletAddress,
        marketAddress,
        setMarketAddress,
        contractABI,
        setContractABI,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AcreDappContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useAcreDapp() {
  const context = React.useContext(AcreDappContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAcreDapp must be used within a AcreDappProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export { AcreDappProvider, useAcreDapp };
```

**NavItem.tsx**

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavItem(props: { link: string, children: ReactNode | ReactNode[] }) {
    return (
        <Link
        to={props.link}
        type="button"
        className="inline-flex items-center px-6 py-3 border-none text-base rounded-xl text-dark-grey bg-none hover:bg-light-grey-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-logo-green"
      >
        {props.children}
      </Link>
    );
}

export default NavItem;
```

**Navbar.tsx**

```js
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { linkTo } from "../../utils/uiUtils";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
//Hooks
import { useAcreDapp } from "../../providers/AcreDappProvider/AcreDappProvider";
import useOwnedNFTs from "../../hooks/useOwnedNFTs";
import { useConnectWallet } from "@web3-onboard/react";
// components
import RoundedButton from "../RoundedButton/RoundedButton";
import NavItem from "../NavItem/NavItem";

// media
import horizontalLogoGreenImg from "../../media/horizontal-logo-green.svg";
import circleLogoGreenImg from "../../media/circle-logo-green.svg";



function Navbar(props: {
  bg?: "transparent" | "white" | "grey";
  hideLogo?: boolean;
}) {
  const [NftData, setNftData] = useState({
    ownerAddress: "",
    name: "",
    description: "",
    image: "",
    externalUrl: "",
    contractAddress: "",
    tokenId: "",
    blockchain: null,
    metaverse: "",
    symbol: "",
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [{ wallet, connecting }, connect, disconnect] = useConnectWallet();
  const { walletAddress, walletContext } = useAcreDapp();
  const { ownedNFTs, fetchSuccess } = useOwnedNFTs();
  const supabase = createClient( // Move into Acre app context
    `https://${process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL}.supabase.co`,
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_API_KEY}`
  );
  console.log('Context', walletContext)
  let ethersProvider;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (wallet) {
      ethersProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
        wallet.provider,
        "any"
      );
      let web3 = document.querySelector("onboard-v2") as HTMLElement;
      web3.style.display = "none";
      let nftArray: Array<{}> = [];
      const nakedDB = async () => {
        try {
          console.log(ownedNFTs)
          setLoading(true);
          let { data, error, status } = await supabase
            .from("Users")
            .upsert({
              wallet_address: wallet?.accounts[0].address,
              NFTS: ownedNFTs,
            })
            .eq("wallet_address", wallet?.accounts[0].address);
          if (error && status !== 406) {
            throw error;
          }
          if(status){
            console.log("Database status: ", status, data);
          };
        } catch (error) {
          console.table(error);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };
      nakedDB();
    } else {
      let web3 = document.querySelector("onboard-v2") as HTMLElement;
      web3.style.display = "";
    }
  }, [wallet]);

  let bgClasses = "bg-white";
  let hideLogoClasses = props.hideLogo ? "invisible" : "";

  switch (props.bg) {
    case "transparent":
      bgClasses = "";
      break;
    case "white":
      bgClasses = "bg-white";
      break;
    case "grey":
      bgClasses = "bg-lighter-grey";
      break;
    default:
      bgClasses = "bg-blue";
      break;
  }

  return (
    <nav
      className={`${bgClasses} z-10 relative px-6 md:px-20 py-auto sm:h-nav-sm md:h-nav-md lg:h-nav-lg xl:h-nav-xl flex items-center justify-between`}
    >
      <div>
        <Link to="/">
          <img
            src={horizontalLogoGreenImg}
            alt="Acre logo"
            className={`${hideLogoClasses} h-8 md:inline-block hidden`}
          ></img>
          <img
            src={circleLogoGreenImg}
            alt="Acre logo"
            className={`${hideLogoClasses} h-8 md:hidden`}
          ></img>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">
        <NavItem link="/property/list/landing">List Property</NavItem>
        <NavItem link="/explore">Explore</NavItem>
        <NavItem link="/account/properties">Rent/Sell</NavItem>
        <NavItem link="/resources">Resources</NavItem>
      </div>
      <div>
        {!walletContext ? (
          <>
            {" "}
            <RoundedButton onClick={() => connect()}>
              {connecting
                ? "connecting"
                : walletAddress
                ? "Disconnect"
                : "Connect Wallet"}
            </RoundedButton>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <RoundedButton grey={true} link="/account/notifications">
              Account
            </RoundedButton>
            <RoundedButton onClick={() => disconnect({label: `${walletContext.label}`})}>
              Disconnect
            </RoundedButton>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

**Explore Page**

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { linkTo } from '../utils/uiUtils';


// components
import AcreMap from '../components/AcreMap/AcreMap';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';
import PropertySearch from '../components/PropertySearch/PropertySearch';
import PropertyCard from '../components/PropertyCard/PropertyCard';

function ExplorePage() {
    const searchedProperties = useSearchedProperties();

    return <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="sm:h-full-nav-sm md:h-full-nav-md lg:h-full-nav-lg xl:h-full-nav-xl flex flex-col">
            <PropertySearch></PropertySearch>
            <div className="flex flex-grow sm:h-full-search-sm md:h-full-search-md lg:h-full-search-lg xl:h-full-search-xl">
                <div className="flex-grow relative h-full">
                    <AcreMap />
                </div>
                <div className="p-4 overflow-scroll h-full">
                    <div className="text-lg font-bold mb-4">{ searchedProperties.length } listings available</div>
                    <ul className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                        {
                            searchedProperties.map(property =>{
                                return <PropertyCard key={`${property.address}_${property.tokenId}`} property={property} size="sm" />
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </>;
}

export default ExplorePage;
```

I have tried modifying my provider location to wrap around the `App` component. I am not sure what the issue is.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this relevant https://github.com/blocknative/web3-onboard/issues/1209?

Comment: How are you linking/navigating between routes? What debugging steps have been taken? What are the *exact* steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @jme11 Its not relevant. I am getting the address, its just on the initial load.

Comment: @DrewReese I am using the <Link> Component

Comment: Where is any link component? Please include all relevant code as part of a [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the code above to show the Navitem component which the navbar uses

Comment: Where is `Navbar` rendered? Is it rendered within the same router rendering the routes? Can you share the `ExplorePage ` component so we can see what it might be doing when it mounts?

Comment: @DrewReese The Navbar is a component thats imported into each page. I have updated the code to involve the Explore page. Its not functional yet and just uses dummy data

Comment: What is the `useSearchedProperties` hook doing when the component mounts? The gist here is to find/figure out what specifically occurs when the `ExplorePage` is navigated to. You could also just comment out a bunch of code to see if you can navigate to `"/explore"` without issue. Incrementally comment back in a line of code at-a-time to see where the code breaks.

Comment: @DrewReese I appreciate your help! I did find a solution, but another bug came up that ill post about.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In my context provider I wrapped the `useEffect()` function in a conditional that only set the state `if` the **wallet** was true.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (wallet) {
    setWalletAddress(wallet.accounts[0].address);
   
    }
    
  }, [wallet]);
```